# CMake GUI on Mac

Tags: macos, cmake, macports

I can't find where I can get the GUI tool for `CMake` on `MacOSX`. I see references to it online but nothing else. I got `CMake` using `MacPorts` but on Windows I am used to using the GUI.

Does it exist on Mac and where/how do I get it?

Comment: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html
Link is above! In case you need more info about it, just check out the link below.
http://www.cmake.org/cmake/project/about.html

Comment: Nowadays the easiest way to install CMake GUI is `brew cask install cmake` (note the `cask` -- `brew install cmake` only includes the CLI version)

Comment: Nowadays `brew install --cask cmake`. And it fails saying cmake already installed. So, how to install make-gui on macOS?

Comment: @KcFnMi I was in the same boat - could not find a way to successfully install cmake-gui through homebrew but was able to use @Andrew's solution below using macports (`sudo port install cmake +qt5`)

Answer (score 26):

you need to install the gui variant:

```
sudo port install cmake +gui
```

you may need to run sudo port uninstall cmake first.

Comment: The variant is now `+qt5`

Answer (score 21):

`Cask` is outdated now. You can install `cmake` using:

```
brew install --cask cmake
```

Answer (score 12):

Try installing the cmake GUI using brew cask

```
brew cask install cmake
```

how to install brew cask

1. Install Homebrew first [How to install homebrew](https://brew.sh)
2. Add the brew cask to using the command `brew tap caskroom/cask`

Comment: Ah, didn't realize the cask version of cmake has the gui. But fyi the "brew tap" command isn't necessary anymore. "brew cask" should work out of the box. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58335410/error-caskroom-cask-was-moved-tap-homebrew-cask-cask-instead

Comment: At the time of this comment, this method does not work. Perhaps the cask has removed the gui program since this answer was written.

Comment: It's now called ` brew install --cask cmake`

Answer (score 1):

here it is:

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html

extra plugins will imported by their own extensions so no OS compatibility is needed ;)