# Error: caskroom/cask was moved. Tap homebrew/cask-cask instead

Tags: macos, homebrew, torch, macos-catalina, homebrew-cask

I try to go through installation process [Github](https://github.com/jcjohnson/neural-style/blob/master/INSTALL.md) on MacOs Catalina

The first step is to execute in Terminal:

```
cd ~/
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/ezinstall/master/install-deps | bash
```

But I get Error:

```
Error: caskroom/cask was moved. Tap homebrew/cask-cask instead.
```

Then I tried:

```
brew tap caskroom/cask
```

But I got the same error. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You don't need to install cask anymore, you just need homebrew. Try using any cask command

Comment: I tried entering "cask" in terminal. And the error is "-bash: cask: command not found"

Comment: I think I understand. when I wrote brew cask , it gave me options

Comment: It's error about file path. It's better that just follow hint `Tap homebrew/cask-cask instead`.

Comment: Just install gimp using `brew cask install gimp` rather than `brew tap caskroom/cask && brew cask install gimp`. Thanks!

Comment: @rize the issue is that the 'brew cask' command does not work. Jurgen is correct: 'brew install --cask [name]' is how it is written now

Answer (score 9):

tap from homebrew instead of caskroom:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-fonts
```

Answer (score 5):

//this code error:

```
brew tap caskroom/fonts
Error: caskroom/fonts was moved.
```

//the correct code.

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-fonts
brew cask install font-fira-code
brew install --cask font-fira-code (the new working way)
```

Comment: The second line of correct code didn't work for me. The first line did but the second line should be updated to brew install font-fira-code

Answer (score 1):

OK, I understand, just type in `brew cask`, and wait...

```
MyMacBook-Pro:homebrew-core adam$ brew cask
==> Tapping homebrew/cask
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 3581, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3581/3581), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3573/3573), done.
remote: Total 3581 (delta 23), reused 578 (delta 6), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (3581/3581), 1.19 MiB | 18.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (23/23), done.
Tapped 1 command and 3470 casks (3,586 files, 3.9MB).
Homebrew Cask provides a friendly CLI workflow for the administration
of macOS applications distributed as binaries.

Commands:

    --cache    display the file used to cache the Cask
    audit      verifies installability of Casks
    cat        dump raw source of the given Cask to the standard output
    create     creates the given Cask and opens it in an editor
    doctor     checks for configuration issues
    edit       edits the given Cask
    fetch      downloads remote application files to local cache
    home       opens the homepage of the given Cask
    info       displays information about the given Cask
    install    installs the given Cask
    list       with no args, lists installed Casks; given installed Casks, lists staged files
    outdated   list the outdated installed Casks
    reinstall  reinstalls the given Cask
    style      checks Cask style using RuboCop
    uninstall  uninstalls the given Cask
    upgrade    upgrades all outdated casks
    zap        zaps all files associated with the given Cask

See also "man brew-cask"
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install cask now. But the command has changed a bit. Like if you want to install java, you need to use:

```
brew install --cask homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go.

`brew install alfred`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and had to do the following...

1. Installing cask

```
echo "installing caskroom"
brew tap caskroom/cask;
```

2. Then I was able to install applications as normal (e.g. Java)

```
echo "installing java"
brew cask install java;
java -version;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while reading the book, *Docker Up and Running*. While working through the installation chapter, I was working through installing Virtual Box on my Mac and encountered the problem referenced by this question. Note that at the time of this answer, for Macs, at least, you don't need to install Cask, as stated above. However, you also can't run the `brew cask <my-command>` anymore either. You'll instead need to run Cask commands in the form:

```
brew <my-command> --cask
```

I hope this helps you as it helped me.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not have homebrew installed on your mac, you can install it via

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

To install java(latest version) just use below command

```
brew install java
```