# CMake gui on MacOS

Tags: macos, homebrew, cmake-gui

I am trying to install cmake-gui on macOS, I already have cmake 3.27.6 and home-brew installed. What is the best way to install the cmake gui without macports through home-brew.I tried to follow this [CMake GUI on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044251/cmake-gui-on-mac) ,but didn't work for me .

I have tried following attempts ,but none seems to be working for me.
1.sudo port install cmake +gui that led to sudo: port: command not found ;
2.brew install --cask cmake , led to Error: It seems there is already a Binary at '/opt/homebrew/bin/cpack'
3.brew cask install cmake ,led to Error: `brew cask` is no longer a `brew` command. Use `brew <command> --cask` instead.

Comment: Did you get any luck? I encountered the same issue.

Comment: No. How about you ?

Comment: No luck for me either